# How can i force to download a doc file my project requirement is when to click a button force to download a doc file

Tags: php

i am getting 64bit encoded path through url parameter and then successfully decoding it but when i click button on which i have linked that php page i am getting the my same php page not the file.

```
$path;
if (isset($_GET['path'])){
    $path=$_GET['path'];
}
$path=base64_decode($path);
$file_url = $path;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;");
readfile($file_url);
header("Location: page.php");
```

Comment: Is the button an `a` tag with a `href` or a `button` tag sitting inside a `form`? can you post that part of the code?